# Unpausing a game when a TouchScreenButton node is released

Tags: input, godot, touch

I'm making a mobile game in the Godot game engine.
I made a spike scene where the spikes will respawn at a random time in a particular position moving upwards.
Then I instanced the scene in the main scene, it worked perfectly, the spikes moving up and appearing in a particular position.
Then I created a TouchScreenButton node in the main scene and changed it pause property to process and then added a _OnPressed and _OnReleased signal to the main scene script then added this code to the _OnPressed function
`get_tree().paused = true`
And added this code to the _OnReleased function
`get_tree().paused = false`

But when ever I press and release the button it only pauses the scene

What should I do?

Comment: Are you saying it does not unpause? Or are you saying there is something that should pause but doesn't? By the way, if you have a shader that uses TIME they do not pause. You might also be interested in [`Engine.time_scale`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_engine.html#class-engine-property-time-scale) which will affect such shaders.

Answer (score 0):

The main node will not be able to receive signals when the tree is paused and it's pause mode is set to `inherit`. You should handle the signals in a node that has it's pause mode set to `process`.